# Why concatenating string and undefined does Not raise an error in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

For example, this code is not valid:

```typescript
function fn1(a: number, b?: number) {
  console.log(a + b);  // error 'b' is possibly 'undefined'.(18048)
}
fn1(5);
```

But this code is valid:

```typescript
function fn2(a: string, b?: string) {
  console.log(a + b);  // valid code
}
fn2('Hi');
```

Why doesn't Typescript in strict mode raise an error in the second case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The authoritative answer to this question can be found in [a comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2093#issuecomment-75326820) on [microsoft/TypeScript#2093](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2093) by the development lead of the TypeScript team at Microsoft:

> There's a huge amount of code out there that does stuff like this:
>
> ```
> console.log("Foo is " + x);
> ```
>
> where `x` might be a function, `undefined` or `null`, in which case explicitly calling `toString()` would be a bad idea. We made the decision that adding *anything* to a string is so often done that it is not ever an error.
>
> [This suggestion] doesn't meet the bar for introducing a breaking change in the language.

So that's the answer: whether or not you agree with it, the TypeScript team didn't want to break existing real-world code that concatenates random stuff to strings.

---

In that issue and similar issues (such as [microsoft/TypeScript#7989](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7989), [microsoft/TypeScript#42983](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42983), and  [microsoft/TypeScript#48962](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/48962)), it is mentioned that those who really want to see this functionality and are willing to use ESLint could enable [the `@typescript-eslint/restrict-plus-operands` rule](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/restrict-plus-operands/) which will issue errors when using `+` to concatenate values of different types.  So there are options out there, even if they are not part of TypeScript directly.

Answer (score 0):

Because in concatenation, if the first value is `string` JavaScript will force the second value to be `string` that is why the compiler does not care if `b` may be undefined, since you can concatenate anything with a `string`.

However, if you try to make `a` of type `number`, or try any other operation the error will occur :

```
function fn2(a: number, b?: string) {
  console.log(a + b);  // 'b' is possibly 'undefined'
}
fn2(5);
```

Comment: I believe in strict mode this should be an error...

Comment: strict mode has nothing to do with that

Answer (score 0):

I have a different thought

I think string + undefined is acceptable because it is a valid JS operation

but number cannot concatenate undefined surprise me because it is also a valid JS operation

Comment: It's valid to do number + undefined. It's NaN. But string + undefined is "stringundefined".

Comment: yes, which is why I do not understand why TS would stop you from concatenating number to undefined